# DialogFragment on Fragment with screen rotation

Tags: android, rotation, fragment

On my main activity I have a Fragment in which I apply setRetainInstance(true) so that the AsyncTask I use into it is not disturbed by orientation change.

A lot of work is processed by the AsyncTask. That's why I would like to display a dialog with a progressBar on top of my activity.

I made some researches and I succeed in doing with a DialogFragment:

public class DialogWait extends DialogFragment {

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;

public DialogWait() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_wait, container);

    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Hello");
    setCancelable(false);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

    return view;
}

public void updateProgress(int value) {
    progressBar.setProgress(value);
}
```

And here is my AsyncTask:

```
public class InitAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

private Context activity;
private OnTaskDoneListener mCallback;
private DialogWait dialog;

public InitAsyncTask(Context context, OnTaskDoneListener callback, DialogWait dialogWait) {
    activity = context;
    mCallback = callback;
    dialog = dialogWait;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    doStuff();

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    dialog.updateProgress(values[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {     
    publishProgress(100);
            if(dialog != null)
         dialog.dismiss();
    mCallback.onTaskDone();
}

private void doStuff() {
          //...
    }
```

}

If I don't change the screen rotation, it works fine. But if I do, the dialog is dismissed and a few seconds later, I got a NullPointerEsception which nonsense since I set the condition: if(dialog != null)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found!

I was not doing the right thing with the Fragment containing my AsyncTask.

Because, I haven't really understood the concept of orientation in Fragment, I get it thanks to this link: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

Override `onCreate`, and `onDestroyView` methods in your `DialogWait` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);        
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance()) {
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Comment: @Shajeel you shouldn't use setRetainInstance with UI fragments, i assume dialogframents automatically fit this description?